# ADO.NET Data Services for MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, wcf-data-services

Hey!  I've searched high and low for this, and no luck.  Is there a way that CRUD methods for a MySQL install (Linux box) be exposed via <strike>ADO.NET</strike> WCF Data Services?  I would really love to leverage this in my WPF app :)

Thank u!

#### EDIT:

:D I am aware that it's called *Windows* Communication Foundation, but just thought I'd put it out there and hope that it **is** possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to use a something like a MySql to linq provider and host the wcf service on a windows server box which connects to the mysql linux box in the usual connection string way.

So you will need windows server as well as the linux one hosting the mysql database, unless you want to move the mysql instance to the same windows box.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

<strike>Couple of potential links which could help ... [here](http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/LINQ-To-MySQL.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysqlnhibernate.aspx)</strike>

Have a look at the [Mono WCF Core](http://www.mono-project.com/WCF) stack, this might be better for you.

Comment: thanx 4your reply! Yeah, but my only reason for going the MySQL/Linux route is because I am writing a basic app for a small business.  Windows Server 2008 SBS + SQL Server 2005 + 15 CALs will blow their budget.  (Sorry, I had to mention that last point as it is the truth)

Comment: That sounds fair, I've updated the answer with a link to the Mono WCF information. I've not used it so I can't comment on how featured it is. Hope this helps.

Comment: Definitely looks like a great place to start, THANK U!!!  dont know why I didnt think of looking on Mono's Web :$

Comment: I've also come across OData (http://www.odata.org) which is an open data sharing protocol made available by Microsoft.  Not too sure at this stage if it can help me achieve what I want, but I am currently looking thru the docs/faqs now.